How to Connect Stripe Payment Gateway to My Hostinger eCommerce Website for Indian Payments?
I'm building an eCommerce website using Hostinger's Website Builder and I want to integrate Stripe as the payment gateway for handling transactions in India. I'm aware that Stripe supports Indian payment methods such as UPI, Credit/Debit Cards, and Net Banking, but I'm unsure how to properly configure the integration.


"I am experiencing the same issue and have reached out to Hostinger's support team. They have informed me that the problem is expected to be resolved in an upcoming update, and they have advised waiting until the update is released."
